# Visualize Yes/ No tree using Graphviz

Tags: python, tree, graphviz

I have a symptom diagnosis questionnaire data in the following form (python) :
List of dictionaries of paths . here is an example of symptom diagnosis with first initial symptom (A) and 2 questions after it.

```
 qa=  [OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 0), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 0), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 1), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 1), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 1), ('D', 1), ('C', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 1), ('D', 1), ('C', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 1), ('D', 0), ('C', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 1), ('D', 0), ('C', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 0), ('D', 1), ('C', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 0), ('D', 1), ('C', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 0), ('D', 0), ('C', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 0), ('E', 0), ('D', 0), ('C', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 0), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 0), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 1), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 1), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 1), ('C', 0), ('D', 0), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 1), ('D', 0), ('E', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 1), ('D', 0), ('E', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 0), ('E', 1), ('D', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 0), ('E', 1), ('D', 0)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 0), ('E', 0), ('D', 1)]),
 OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 0), ('F', 0), ('C', 0), ('E', 0), ('D', 0)])]
```

While 1= YES , 0 = NO

I would like to plot the diagnosis in a decision  tree format where each node split into 'YES" / 'NO' edges that lead to the next node and so.

i grouped the "yes" and "no" when both are available for same question because it run over the node
using graphviz:

```
u = Digraph(name, strict=True ,filename='blabla',format='png',node_attr={'color': 'mediumpurple1', 'style': 'filled'})
u.attr(size='16,16')
answer_map = ['No','Yes']
nodes = []
edges = []
for path in qa:
    questions = [f'{j}_{lev}' for lev,j in enumerate(path.keys(), 1)]
    questions = [w.replace(':', '_') for w in questions]
    answers = [answer_map[item] for item in path.values()] 
    for i in range(len(questions)-1):
        #u.edge(questions[i], questions[i+1],label=answers[i])
        nodes.append((questions[i],questions[i+1]))
        edges.append(answers[i])
d = {'nodes':nodes,'edges':edges}
df_graph = pd.DataFrame(d).drop_duplicates()
df_graph_joined = df_graph.groupby('nodes')['edges'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

for row in df_graph_joined.itertuples():
    u.edge(row.nodes[0],row.nodes[1],label=row.edges)
u.render()
```

[image]

But ,as you can see , it is impossible to  distinguish the diagnosis path. i would like to split the  tree  in each "yes"/"no" junction so by looking at the tree i can see each diagnostic path. How do i do that?

And i would like it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: I note that there is no question here.  It would be easier to help you if you a) showed what you've done so far and b) provided a diagram showing your desired result (hand drawn is OK)

Comment: @sroush thank you , i've updated the question ,added code and a plot

Comment: Please add a drawing of what you try to archive too, e.g. by hand modifying the supplied drawing

Comment: @Jens i've added drawing of the tree. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split in each answer,  you need to edit the nodes to distinct names. I suggest changing a node name by the full path. For example, for this OrderedDict:

```
('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('F', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 1)
```

You can use something like this:

```
root, root-A1, root-A1-B1, root-A1-B1-F1, root-A1-B1-F1-C1, root-A1-B1-F1-C1-D1
```

In this example:

- root represents A
- root-A1  represents  B, which path is A--> 1
- root-A1-B1 represents F, which path is A --> 1 --> B --> 1

Here is an example:

```py
# New node names
qa_tree = []
for path in qa:
    prefix = 'root'
    path_tree = OrderedDict()
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(path.items()):
        key_tree = '{}'.format(prefix)
        prefix += '-{}{}'.format(key, value)
        path_tree[key_tree] = {'value': value, 'name': key}
    qa_tree.append(path_tree)

name = 'test'
u = Digraph(name, strict=True ,filename='blabla',format='png',node_attr={'color': 'mediumpurple1', 'style': 'filled'})
u.attr(size='16,16')
answer_map = ['No','Yes']
nodes = []
edges = []

for path in qa_tree:
    questions = [key for i, key in enumerate(path.keys(), 1)]
    answers = [answer_map[item.get('value')] for item in path.values()] 
    names = [item.get('name') for item in path.values()] 
    for i in range(len(questions)-1):
        u.node(questions[i], label = names[i])
        u.node(questions[i+1], label = names[i+1] )
        u.edge(questions[i], questions[i+1], label=answers[i])
u.render()
```

[image]